# Javascript passing element Id as argument

Tags: javascript, html

I need a bunch of sliders in a html page. I have found [this example in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_rangeslider) to be exactly what I need.

There, the following script handles the update for exactly one hard coded slider:

```
<body>

<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
<p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>

</body>
```

The qustion is if I add more sliders to the HTML page how can I generalize that script? I do not want to have a pair of slider and output and oninput functions for each slider that I need in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class names and target the container element, something like this:

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".slidecontainer");

for(let container of containers) {
  const slider = container.querySelector(".slider");
  const output = container.querySelector(".value");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
<p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
  <p>Value: <span class="value"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
  <p>Value: <span class="value"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider">
  <p>Value: <span class="value"></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give slider and output label as parameters to function

```js
function setSlider(slider, output){
  var slider = document.getElementById(slider);
  var output = document.getElementById(output);
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }

}

setSlider("myRange1", "demo1")
setSlider("myRange2", "demo2")
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
<p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange1">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange2">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("slidecontainer");
elements.forEach(function(el){
  var slider = el.getElementById("myRange");
  var output = el.getElementById("demo");
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;

  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
  }

})
```

now for every slider you add it will work meaning you just need to add the html with the corresponding class

```
</head>
<body>

<h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>
<p>Drag the slider to display the current value.</p>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
```

Will yield two working sliders with no additional declaration.

So what im doing is looking for every element that has the slidercontainer class and iterating through each one. this way for every slider with that structure you'll have a slider. without the need of adding additional javascript to refer to each slider